# AngularJS angular.forEach doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I think this is a stupid error but I'm still trying to make this work, I have a simple values variable which contains something like this: `{A1: true, A2: false, A3: false, A4: false, A5: false, …}`.

And I want to iterate through it using angular.forEach like this:

```
angular.forEach(scope.values, function(element, key) {
           console.log(element);
           console.log(key);
});
```

The scope.values is not empty and looks like the example given above, but why it's not working? No one of the console.log is showing something.

Comment: Post actual code. What you have is not a valid JS array, and is not a valid JS object either.

Comment: So if I transform it to an object  in the declaration it should works ?

Comment: I have no idea what your declaration looks like in the first place, and thus what you actually want to achieve. What you posted is not valid code, so I can't know what it's supposed to be in reality. Post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you hace a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kueduc7s/3/

```
 var obj = [{
        "item" : "Apples",
        "cost" : 12,
        "actno":12563456,
        "viewer":"asdad",
        "viewer1":"asdad",
        "viewer2":"asdad"

    },
    {
        "item" : "Apples",
        "cost" : 15,
        "actno":44545454,
        "viewer":"asd",
        "viewer1":"sdasd",
        "viewer2":"asdasdadad"
    }];
    angular.module("forEachMod", [])
        .controller("forEachCtrl", function($scope){
            $scope.result = [];

            angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key){
            alert(value.item)
            $scope.result.push({'test1':value.item,'test2':value.cost,'test3':value.viewer,'test4':{"subtest":value.viewer2}})
                console.log($scope.result);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I transform my array to an object